# What drives search rankings on posts (both internal site and Google searches)?

Tags: support, search, up-votes, views

What influences findability on a post?

1. Upvotes
2. Views
3. Asked date
4. Last active time

How is this done in the Stack Exchange internal search engine? And how does Google do it?

Why is it that when searching on Google for 'iPhone development stackoverflow' the fourth result is *[Best book / resources for learning iOS programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403049/best-book-resources-for-learning-ios-programming)*?

Comment: Including the word "stackoverflow" in the search terms is basically cheating...

Comment: What do you mean with this?

Comment: If you add "stackoverflow" to the search terms, of course you're gonna get results from stackoverflow. So you can't have that term if you want to compare the searchability of stackoverflow in relation to other sources.

Comment: @Mysticial He's wondering what determines the results among various SO posts.

Comment: @Servy Oh, within SO itself. Guess I misread.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11387/why-does-insert-favorite-search-engine-here-get-better-search-results-than-so/26667#26667

Comment: And also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange

Comment: Google's ranking implementation isn't publicly available. So there won't be any definitive answer here.

Comment: @dystroy I'm sure there's some SEO *experts* who would love to chime in with their *knowledge* :p