# Does the question score have an influence on google rating?

Tags: discussion, search-engine, popular-question

Could someone from the dev team explain what defines the rank of SE question in Google search (or Bing search, if it happens to be different)? Do search engines define the rank independently based on their own click and search request statistics, or do they take into account some data from SE? For example, would upvoting a question make it rank higher than a similar non-upvoted question?

I understand the number of views of a question should correlate with its page rank, but is this a coincidence (more views also means more views via  search engines) or is the information about page views statistics accessible to search engines?

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163832/what-drives-search-rankings-on-posts-both-internal-site-and-google-searches

Comment: It might. We don't know. We don't work for Google/other services and don't know what algorithms they use for determining that. All we can do is speculate.

Comment: @animuson OK then. I expected there to be some sort of cooperation between search engines and big-impact sites.

Comment: @animuson BTW, if your speculations go beyond self-evident assertions (like "linking increases page rank, so question with a lot of links rank better"), I'd like to read them even if they are just guesses.